# Дублировать инлайн кнопки в обычыне

Tags: python, aiogram

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    row = []
    row.append(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Забрать подарок ", callback_data="btn3"))
    row.append(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Поддержка ", callback_data="btn4"))
    
    
    # Добавляем обычные кнопки в инлайн-клавиатуру
    row.append(types.KeyboardButton(text="Забрать подарок "))
        
        
    
    keyboard.add(*row)
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f'Добро пожаловать', reply_markup=keyboard)




@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'btn3')
async def user_id_inline_callback(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    row = []
    row.append(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Подписаться", url=""))
    row.append(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Я подписался, забрать подарок", callback_data='chek_sub'))
    keyboard.add(*row)
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=callback_query.from_user.id, text="Остался один шаг до подарка: подпишись на нашу группу с розыгрышами и большими скидками на товары, а потом возвращайся сюда за своим подарком.", reply_markup=keyboard)
```

Вот часть моего кода, как видите я уже попытался добавить, но не вышло.
Как можно реализовать мою задумку и продублировать клавиатуру, чтоб она еще и работала?

Comment: обычные кнопки - это какие?

Comment: ReplyKeyboardMarkup кнопки